# web hosted qgis project with selectable layers

Tags: hosting, openlayers, qgis

I am new to gis and still not clear of capabilities/requirements for hosting, so please be patient.

I am trying to create an MVP of hosting a qgis project on the web using with qgis-server. For this demo, I have a simple project application with 2 layers. I have been able to host it on a digital ocean server using an external web address and show/toggle the layers using OpenLayers cdn... [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiyR7.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>QGIS WMS</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/ol.css">

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="locationsCheckbox" checked>Locations<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="virtualCheckbox" checked>Virtual Layer<br>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="popup" style="display: none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var locationsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://qgis-server.mysite.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'locations', 'VERSION': '1.3.0', 'FORMAT': 'image/png', 'MAP': '/home/qgis/world.qgz'},
            serverType: 'qgis'
        }),
        visible: true, 
        title: "Locations"
    });

    var virtualLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://qgis-server.mysite.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'virtual_layer', 'VERSION': '1.3.0', 'FORMAT': 'image/png', 'MAP': '/home/qgis/world.qgz'},
            serverType: 'qgis'
        }),
        visible: true, 
        title: "Virtual Layer"
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [baseLayer, locationsLayer, virtualLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

    // Handle visibility control
    document.getElementById('locationsCheckbox').addEventListener('change', function() {
        locationsLayer.setVisible(this.checked);
    });

    document.getElementById('virtualCheckbox').addEventListener('change', function() {
        virtualLayer.setVisible(this.checked);
    });

    // Get feature info
    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = ''; // Clear the previous popup content
        var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
        var url = virtualLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}); // 'text/html' can be changed to 'application/json' if your server supports it
        if (url) {
            fetch(url)
                .then(function(response) { return response.text(); })
                .then(function(html) {
                    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = html;
                    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
                });
        }
    });

    // Hide the popup when the map is moved
    map.on('moveend', function() {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, is there a way to host the qgis project natively? Meaning... upload qgis project and tie into hosting where layers are automatically available, as if you are viewing the project on the web with layer toggles. Without having to bring in a third party (like OpenLayers) and needing to define the layers specifically. I was expecting qgis-server do this natively, but it has been difficult finding examples of exactly what to expect from qgis-server.